# Access array data from SQL column in PHP

Tags: php, sql

I have some SQL code that returns the a result `{"agreetotos":"1","number":"0412345678","signupip":"123.456.789.10"}`

I can access this data using PHP and output it as it appears above.

How can I, using PHP, access just the value for the key`"number"`

the result `{ }` contains varying amounts of data, hence I need to search for the key `"number"` and return the value `"0412345678"` (etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output is json, you can decode it and convert it to an array:

```
$json = '{"agreetotos":"1","number":"0412345678","signupip":"123.456.789.10"}';
$array = json_decode($json, true); //convert it to an array
//then

$number = $array['number']; //0412345678
```

Comment: doh! json_decode, of course. I even said to myself at one point 'it looks like json' -- thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php
json_deconde will convert this string to PHP table, and then you can simply do

```
echo $table['number'];
```